# making something similar to a constructor in a constroller Symfony 2

Tags: php, routes, symfony

I am using symfony 2 for a project. I have a controller where I make several checks before each function and what I want is to make symfony fire that function on every request for that controller. For example

```
class ChatController extends Controller
{
    public function put()
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $this->checkSomething(); //just a custom function
        $this->checkSomethingElse(); //another custom function
        // do something
    }

    public function get()
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $this->checkSomething(); //just a custom function
        $this->checkSomethingElse(); //another custom function
        // do something
    }
}`
```

I want to achieve the same thing as :

```
class ChatController extends Controller
{
    private $user;

    public function init()
    {
        $this->user = $this->getUser();
        $this->checkSomething(); //just a custom function
        $this->checkSomethingElse(); //another custom function
    }

    public function put()
    {
        //here i can access $this->user          
        // do something
    }

    public function get()
    {
        //here i can access $this->user
        // do something
    }
}`
```

So basically what I want is to make a function behave like a constructor. Can this be done in Symfony2 ?

Comment: This should be possible, check the kernel and hooks but you might need to change your design a bit. See [Event Dispatcher](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/index.html) in the cookbook and the [Event Dispatcher Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two idiomatic ways of achieving this:

1. [Event listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#events) and
2. [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) — using [JMSAopBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSAopBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst) in Symfony2.

Using constructors for this use case is a Bad Idea™. Hacking into a constructor or a setter for checks not related to instantiating an object or setting a value is just that — a hack. It's not logical nor idiomatic in any sense. It's like hitting nails with your head — doable, but better options exist.

Comment: why is it a bad idea , plz do tell

Comment: There is no quick answer as to why it is bad.  But once you get a few controllers written then you will probably find that you really don't need to or want to always execute functions.  You can use my down voted answer to get started.  After which it will probably become clearer why it is not needed.

Comment: Updated my answer with an explanation.

Answer (score -2):

You could override setContainer and it will serve the same purpose as construct.

```
public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
{
    parent::setContainer($container);

    // Your stuff
}
```

But you probably don't really need to do this.  I think that as your design evolves, you really won't need the checks or that the functionality is best done with an event listener.  But this can get you started.

Comment: I just love it when people down vote actual answers without any indication why.